# Detect an element inside a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

What is the best way in your experience to detect the existence of an element inside a div?

I'm currently using this:

```
if (($('.parentDiv').width()) > 0){
    //Do something
}
```

There has to be a more elegant way.

Comment: Only elements or text-only too?

Comment: I'm Only after elements not text nodes specifically.

Comment: @Ollie. So `.width()` is broken... it won't be **0** with `<div> foo </div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not what you want, but considering there's at least a little confusing over your requirements, you could consider if anything at all is within the container: elements, text, whatever.

Say you have an empty div:

```
<div class="parentDiv"></div>​
```

Then `$(".parentDiv").html().length == 0` indicates its emptiness.

If the div is not empty:

```
<div class="parentDiv"> </div>​
<div class="parentDiv"><div></div></div>​
```

Then `$(".parentDiv").html().length` will indicate its occupiedness (returning 1 and 11, respectively, in those scenarios.)

If you wish to check only for elements, or specific elements, then `$(".parentDiv").children()` would be the way to go.

Comment: Exactly what I was after, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

**If empty means not even text nodes:**

```
if ($('.parentDiv').contents().length){
    //Do stuff      
}
```

or:

```
$('.parentDiv:not(:empty)') // which is nice...
```

`.contents` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/contents/):

> Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, **including text and comment nodes.**

if you care only of elements and not text nodes:

```
if ($('.parentDiv').children().length){
    //Do stuff      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only care about elements (and not text nodes), you could check to see if the element has any [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
if($('.parentDiv').children().length) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `children()` function

```
$('.parentDiv').children()
```

Comment: The OP asked for detection of elements not text.

Comment: You're right, but read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282396/detect-an-element-inside-a-div-using-jquery#comment13227599_10282396)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $( '.parentDiv' ).children().length > 0 )
{
     // do something
}
```